# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot pair Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth

Dell Vostro 2520
Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Ubuntu 20.04
Windows 10 Pro
Windows 10 Home
Android 11
iPhone 12

I purchased a mini Bluetooth keyboard for use with my Android phone. Brand unknown but the model number is BK3001; there are hundreds available on eBay, Amazon, etc. This keyboard works with Android 11 on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro smartphone, Windows 10 Pro* and Home+, and iPhone. But when on Ubuntu 20.04.x I open the Settings app at Bluetooth and it scans for Bluetooth devices forever without noticing my keyboard, imaginatively named "Bluetooth Keyboard".

After searching AskUbuntu again I tried:

```
~$ bluetoothctl  
Agent registered  
[bluetooth]# power on  
Changing power on succeeded  
[bluetooth]# agent on  
Agent is already registered  
[bluetooth]# default-agent  
Default agent request successful  
[bluetooth]# scan on  
Discovery started  
[bluetooth]#
```

Again discovery finds nothing. Neither does:

```
~$ hcitool scan  
Scanning ...  
  
~$ bt-device -l  
No devices found
```

Shouldn't Bluetooth Just Work? It has been around for quite a while now but although many other devices can find it, Ubuntu 20.04 can't. Any advice please?

* My wife's Lenovo laptop.
+ Dual-booted into Dell Vostro 2520.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but have you confirmed that the keyboard is not already connected to another device when you are having Ubuntu look for it? Associated devices will (usually) not broadcast their existence if already connected to something.

Comment: Pretty sure the keyboard was disconnected from my smartphone at the time. How would you explain Ubuntu 20.04's inability to find *any* other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 1):

I saw this video and it solved my issue. When I tried to pair the device, the pairing required a passcode to be typed in, but the bluetooth GUI doesn't show you the passcode to type in to finish the pairing.

I had to pair the bluetooth devices via command line, as the command line will show you the passcode that needs to be typed in to complete the pairing process.

https://youtu.be/FomPUvv0tSw

Comment: Keyboards do not usually need a code. Are you sure your answer is for a keyboard?

Comment: @David Wrong, a Bluetooth keyboard can ask you for that. I had quite a few Bluetooth keyboards that asked for it.

Comment: I clearly said usually not a wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if the Dell Vostro 2025 is suspended and then awakened later, Bluetooth cannot detect any external Bluetooth devices. So here is how to get the Bluetooth Keyboard BK3001 to pair with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS:

1. In the device previously paired with Bluetooth Keyboard, unpair the keyboard and switch it off.
2. If a record of the Bluetooth keyboard has been saved in the previous device, delete the record.
3. Switch off (Power Off) your computer completely (no restart).
4. Switch your computer on and make sure Bluetooth is switched off. You may have to do this in the in the menu that drops down from the RH end of the screen title bar *and* by opening **Settings** > **Bluetooth** and setting the toggle switch to off.*
5. Now turn over the Bluetooth Keyboard, switch it on, and press the small black activation button. The faint blue pulsing on the upper right of the top of the keyboard indicates pairing is being attempted.
6. Back at Ubuntu, switch **Settings** > **Bluetooth** on.*  You should see a list of detected external devices; be patient as the keyboard may take a little while to display the pairing code.
7. When the pairing code appears, type the string of digits and press the Enter key (easy to overlook). Voilá, Ubuntu and keyboard are paired!

* The title-bar menu and **Settings** > **Bluetooth** may not synchronise. I have seen one show that
Bluetooth is on and the other that it is off. Awakening from sleep also needs to be fixed so that Bluetooth returns to the state is was in before suspension.