# How to pair Apple Magic Keyboard 2 with Ubuntu (20.04)?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple

Is is possible to pair the Apple Magic Keyboard 2 with Ubuntu? How is it done?

*Disclaimer: I researched for this question before buying the keyboard to see if I would have some headache pairing the MK with Ubuntu. Couldn't find anything so I'm posting this question/answer here.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work using the GUI withiout additional hacking (yes, I was surpirsed too).

1. Open bluetooth settings
2. Turn on the Magic Keyboard using the switch on top right
3. The Magic Keyboard should appear, just click to pair with it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to close the Bluetooth center after trying it with that one since it scans all of the time, this costs, and Bluetooth also works when it is closed. And if this does not help so that you cannot just click on the keyboard and get it connected, this may be since it asks for a PIN code / number that this Bluetooth Control center does not show. Then you need to make your way through the command line Bluetooth Control tool, just follow [Ubuntu 20.04 cannot pair Bluetooth Keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/a/1460879/1110856).